# Calculating using a class, money minus bill

Tags: c#

When I calculate for the change  **(MONEY - BILL)**, it always appears **zero (0)**. I don't know where I got it wrong.

This is my class :

```
class changecalc
{
    int a, b;

    public int B
    {
        get { return b; }
        set { b = value; }
    }

    public int A
    {
        get { return a; }
        set { a = value; }
    }
    public changecalc()
    {
        A = 0;
        B = 0;
    }
             public changecalc(int C,int D)
    {
        C = a;
        D = b;
    }
    public int calculate()
    {
       //this is the money-bill
        return a - b;
    }

}
```

In My FORM :

```
if (int.Parse(txtboxmoney.Text) >= int.Parse(txtboxbill.Text)) {
    //display the change
    changecalc aa = new changecalc(int.Parse(txtboxmoney.Text), int.Parse(txtboxbill.Text));
    change.Text = aa.calculate().ToString();

}
else {
    //error if money is lower than the bill
    txtboxmoney.Clear();
    change.Clear();
    MessageBox.Show("Your Money is not enough");
}
```

Where did I miss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following function updates C & D with zeroes while it should update the backing fields, a & b. That leaves the fields a & b defaulted to zeroes and hence the difference is always zero.

```
public changecalc(int C,int D)
{
    C = a;
    D = b;
}
```

Change the code as follows:

```
public changecalc(int C,int D)
{
    a = C;
    b = D;
}
```

You may also consider refactoring your class:

1. Rename the fields so that they're readable.
2. Remove backing fields (a & b). You don't really need the backing fields for the current use case. The compiler will generate them for you.

Updated code:

```
class ChangeCalculator
{
  public int Money { get; set; }

  public int Bill { get; set; }

  public ChangeCalculator()
  {
     Money = 0;
     Bill = 0;
  }

  public ChangeCalculator(int money, int bill)
  {
     Money = money;
     Bill = bill;
  }

  public int Calculate()
  {
    return Money - Bill;
  }
}
```

Comment: it says doesnt contain a constructor  that takes 2  arguments ?

Comment: Thanks i got it ..

Comment: have updated the name of the function to match the class name. The properties have been marked as public too. please check the updated answer

Comment: Thank you  , it helps a lot

Comment: good to know! :) please accept it as answer if 
 it helped..https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer